# CKEDITOR remove element event

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I using [CKEDITOR](http://ckeditor.com/) for a text, and i want limited number of embed ( video and pictures ) who can upload a user, this mean need count there, problem is it I don't know who to count when a video or picture is delete white backspace. I was trying many way to catch event `change` and `key` but event `key` do not track when you press backspacing and remove a element. And with event `change` I do not see what element was removed or to make a comparation between actual data and previous data. I was try find who undo is implemented but I don't found.

If someone have any ideea who can track when remove a element please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a combination between `change` and `beforeCommandExec` i count number of oembed class and number of img tag, i don't know if is best practice but for moment is only posibility to count your elements.